# How do I run a PyQt ProgressBar dialog window in a multi-threaded environment?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, threadpool

I've been working on this for the last couple of weeks.  I've tried every configuration I can think of with little success.  The basic structure of my actual application starts with a QSystemTrayIcon that houses QActions that run multiple scripts.  Some of those scripts take 10-20 seconds to complete their tasks.  It is fully functional, but I decided I wanted to try to incorporate a QDialog with a QProgressBar and later other widgets.  But for the time being, I'm just starting with a clean QApplication structure to understand how to implement this.

I have created a worker.py containing a countdown.  I would like this to run inside its own QThread.  It'll send out pyqtSignals that I connect to which updates the progress window which runs in its own QThread.

worker.py - has two classes because using the QThreadPool needed a QRunnable, which couldn't emit signals, so I created a QObject as my emitter.

```
from time import sleep
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QRunnable, QObject


class Emitter(QObject):
    signal_worker_count = pyqtSignal(int)
    signal_finished = pyqtSignal()


class WorkerClass(QRunnable):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.max_count = None
        self.emitter = Emitter()

    def countdown(self):
        for i in range(self.max_count, 0, -1):
            self.emitter.signal_worker_count.emit(i)
            sleep(1)
        self.emitter.signal_finished.emit()

    def run(self):
        self.countdown()
```

progress.py has two classes because later I may want a single class, Progress, running multiple potential dialog designs.

progress.py

```
import sys
from time import sleep

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRunnable, QObject
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QProgressBar, QPushButton, QLabel


class Progress(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.bar = None
        self.max_value = None

    def increment_progress(self, progress_value):
        print(self.bar.progress.value() + progress_value)
        self.bar.increment_progress(progress_value)

    def run(self):
        print('starting progress bar')
        new_bar = ProgressDialog()
        new_bar.setup(10)
        self.bar = new_bar
        print('continuing progress bar')
        self.bar.show()
        print('should be showing progress bar')

    def update_progress(self, progress_value):
        self.bar.update_progress(progress_value)


class ProgressDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.progress = None
        self.close_button = None
        self.message_label = None
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Progress Bar')
        self.resize(436, 150)
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.progress = QProgressBar(self)
        self.progress.setObjectName('ProgressBar')
        self.progress.setGeometry(10, 10, 416, 30)

        self.message_label = QLabel(self)
        self.message_label.setObjectName('MessageLabel')
        self.message_label.setGeometry(10, 50, 416, 30)
        self.message_label.setText('Calculating...')

        self.close_button = QPushButton('Close', self)
        self.close_button.setObjectName('CloseButton')
        self.close_button.setGeometry(300, 100, 75, 30)
        self.close_button.setEnabled(True)
        self.close_button.clicked.connect(self.hide)

    def set_message(self, message):
        self.message_label.setText(message)

    def setup(self, max_value):
        self.progress.maximum = max_value

    def increment_progress(self, progress_value):
        self.progress.setValue(self.progress.value() + progress_value)

    def update_progress(self, progress_value):
        self.progress.setValue(progress_value)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    progress = Progress()
    progress.run()
    for i in range(10):
        progress.increment_progress(10)
        sleep(0.5)
    app.exec_()
```

Finally, my main application, and the script that is run, is my QSystemTray object.  It does expect an icon.png file.

system_tray.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThreadPool, QThread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication,
                             QSystemTrayIcon,
                             QMenu,
                             QAction,
                             qApp)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from worker import WorkerClass
from progress import Progress


class SystemTray(QSystemTrayIcon):
    # Override the class constructor
    def __init__(self):
        self.worker_pool = QThreadPool()
        self.worker_pool.setMaxThreadCount(2)
        self.progress_pool = QThreadPool()
        self.progress_pool.setMaxThreadCount(2)

        self.progress = None

        QSystemTrayIcon.__init__(self, QIcon('icon.png'))

        no_progress_action = QAction("Without progress bar", self)
        progress_action = QAction("With progress bar", self)
        quit_action = QAction("Exit", self)

        no_progress_action.triggered.connect(lambda: self.perform("no_progress"))
        progress_action.triggered.connect(lambda: self.perform("progress"))
        quit_action.triggered.connect(lambda: self.perform("quit"))

        tray_menu = QMenu()
        tray_menu.addAction(no_progress_action)
        tray_menu.addSeparator()
        tray_menu.addAction(progress_action)
        tray_menu.addSeparator()
        tray_menu.addAction(quit_action)
        self.setContextMenu(tray_menu)
        self.show()

    def perform(self, req):
        if req == "no_progress":
            no_progress_worker = WorkerClass()
            no_progress_worker.max_count = 10
            no_progress_worker.emitter.signal_worker_count.connect(lambda current_count: print(current_count))
            self.worker_pool.start(no_progress_worker)

        elif req == "progress":
            progress_worker = Progress()
            self.progress_pool.start(progress_worker)
        elif req == "quit":
            self.hide()
            qApp.quit()

    def update_progress(self, current_count):
        print(current_count)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = SystemTray()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Running the system_tray.py file puts an icon in the Windows System Tray.  Right-clicking yields a "without progress" option which runs the worker.py file countdown successfully.  Running the "with progress" option begins the process, but freezes when the Progress Dialog tries to open.

Running the progress.py file on its own runs fine, however, the Dialog tries to show, and we see a countdown of sorts, but the window doesn't officially open until the countdown completes.

I realize that the full code isn't done yet in terms of the worker being linked fully to the progress dialog, but I ran into this problem before I got to that point.

I also tried configuring this with individual QThreads instead of a QThreadPool, with similar results.  Why is my Progress Dialog not showing while my worker countdown() is printing?

Comment: The `progress.py` "works" because you're directly calling the `run` function, but you're not expected to do that, as its purpose is to be *internally* called by the thread manager, which brings to another issue: widgets are **not** thread safe and can **not** be created in external threads. If you want to access or create widgets as a result of a separate thread, you *must* use signals.

Comment: Thank you.  I follow what you're saying about the run function being called by the thread manager.  I'm sure I've done that in one of my iterations, but not this one.  As for the widgets not being thread safe, I did read that somewhere, but I felt like I grasped the concept about 90%.  Would you mind showing me an example of how to create widgets in a separate thread using signals?

Comment: The concept is the same for any QThread related aspect: you connect a signal (emitted from a function that is being run on another thread) to a function that does something in the main thread. In your case, the function would create a widget.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an a modified version of your example that creates the dialog in the main thread and set's it up to receive the signals from the `Emitter` fired by the `WorkerClass`.  I changed it slightly so that both the non-dialog and dialog countdowns would work with the same QRunnable.  I also moved everything into a single file.

```
class Emitter(QObject):
    signal_worker_count = pyqtSignal(int)
    signal_finished = pyqtSignal()


class WorkerClass(QRunnable):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.max_count = 10
        self.emitter = Emitter()

    def run(self):
        for i in range(self.max_count):
            self.emitter.signal_worker_count.emit(i)
            sleep(1)
        self.emitter.signal_finished.emit()


class ProgressDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.progress = None
        self.close_button = None
        self.message_label = None
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Progress Bar')
        self.resize(436, 150)
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.progress = QProgressBar(self)
        self.progress.setObjectName('ProgressBar')
        self.progress.setGeometry(10, 10, 416, 30)
        self.progress.setRange(0,100)

        self.message_label = QLabel(self)
        self.message_label.setObjectName('MessageLabel')
        self.message_label.setGeometry(10, 50, 416, 30)
        self.message_label.setText('Calculating...')

        self.close_button = QPushButton('Close', self)
        self.close_button.setObjectName('CloseButton')
        self.close_button.setGeometry(300, 100, 75, 30)
        self.close_button.setEnabled(True)
        self.close_button.clicked.connect(self.hide)

    def update_progress(self, progress_value):
        self.progress.setValue((progress_value + 1) * 10)


class SystemTray(QSystemTrayIcon):
    # Override the class constructor
    def __init__(self):
        self.worker_pool = QThreadPool()
        self.worker_pool.setMaxThreadCount(2)
        self.progress_pool = QThreadPool()
        self.progress_pool.setMaxThreadCount(2)
        self.progress = None
        QSystemTrayIcon.__init__(self, QIcon('icon.png'))
        no_progress_action = QAction("Without progress bar", self)
        progress_action = QAction("With progress bar", self)
        quit_action = QAction("Exit", self)
        no_progress_action.triggered.connect(lambda: self.perform("no_progress"))
        progress_action.triggered.connect(lambda: self.perform("progress"))
        quit_action.triggered.connect(lambda: self.perform("quit"))
        tray_menu = QMenu()
        tray_menu.addAction(no_progress_action)
        tray_menu.addSeparator()
        tray_menu.addAction(progress_action)
        tray_menu.addSeparator()
        tray_menu.addAction(quit_action)
        self.setContextMenu(tray_menu)
        self.show()

    def perform(self, req):
        if req == "no_progress":
            no_progress_worker = WorkerClass()
            no_progress_worker.setAutoDelete(True)
            no_progress_worker.emitter.signal_worker_count.connect(lambda current_count: print( 10 - current_count))
            self.worker_pool.start(no_progress_worker)
        elif req == "progress":
            progress_worker = WorkerClass()
            progress_worker.setAutoDelete(True)
            self.bar = ProgressDialog()
            self.bar.open()
            progress_worker.emitter.signal_worker_count.connect(self.bar.update_progress)
            self.progress_pool.start(progress_worker)
        elif req == "quit":
            self.hide()
            qApp.quit()
```